# Version 1.0 of the API seems to be here!

Tags: discussion, api

It looks like v1.0 of the API is here now!

I waited a few minutes for an official announcement, but none came - so here it is!

Thanks **a million** to the team for putting this together!

Comment: Those few minutes were us running tests to make sure it was OK to announce.  :)